# Autenticar usuário pelo AD retorna usuário do servidor ao invés do usuário local

Tags: c#, mvc, ad

Tenho uma aplicação web que valida o usuário logado na máquina, carrega suas permissões e abre as telas que lhe são permitidas, sem uso de tela de login.

Pego o usuário com `User.Identity.Name` a partir desse retorno busco as permissões.

No ambiente local (desenvolvimento) a aplicação pega meu usuário corretamente. Porém, quando a aplicação está publicada no servidor, ela pega o usuário do servidor e não o da minha máquina local.

Como faço a aplicação pegar o meu usuário local mesmo ela (aplicação) estando publicada no servidor? É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já experimentou desta forma?

```
User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

É preciso garantir que o seu `web.config` tem o seguinte elemento de autenticação:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Para futura leitura: [Recipe: Enabling Windows Authentication within an Intranet ASP.NET Web application](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application)